# How to stretch System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer?

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player

I'm trying to show a video using the MediaPlayer class. There's an example on [codeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/411827/Using-the-MediaPlayer-in-WPF) I'm looking at.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MediaTimeline timeline = 
              new MediaTimeline(new Uri("airplane.mpg", UriKind.Relative));
            timeline.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            MediaClock clock = timeline.CreateClock();
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.Clock = clock;
            VideoDrawing drawing = new VideoDrawing();
            drawing.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 200);
            drawing.Player = player;
            DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(drawing);
            this.Background = brush;
        }
    }
```

Everything works very well, but I don't know how to stretch the video. Other than using a viewbox, does anyone know how to use System.Windows.Media.Stretch to change the video size?

(Please don't suggest using MediaElement or WpfMediakit or some other classes or external libraries, this question is specifically for System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am dumb, it's actually very easy,

```
    drawing.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, player.NaturalVideoWidth , player.NaturalVideoHeight );
    brush.Stretch =  System.Windows.Media.Stretch.SomeStretchEnum
```